# display_errors value isn't changing in phpinfo()

Tags: php-ini, php

I need to turn display_errors off in PHP. I changed my php.ini (/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini)file.

Also confirmed with phpinfo() that correct file is getting changed: 
Loaded Configuration File --> /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

I changed display_errors to Off everywhere in php.ini.
But the values in phpinfo() for display_errors doesn't change:
display_errors  On  On for both local value as well as master value.

The values in php.ini:

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting = 0
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

I am juggling it for like 2 hours. Any help will be great.
Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question and post your php.ini file here. It helps us and it helps you in finding your solution faster! :)

Comment: Change the other `php.ini` file. The one you chnaged is used by the PHP CLI. The one used by Apache can be found by looking at a `phpinfo()` output. Sorry cannot be more specific about its location I am a dumb Windows user

Comment: What @RiggsFolly says and then restart Apache.

Comment: Of course you are turning these error displays OFF because this is a LIVE site right? You would not do it just to hide the 100's of errors in your code would you? No of course not, _silly me_

Comment: @RiggsFolly :
In my phpinfo(), this is the php.ini file mentioned.
The values in phpinfo() : 
Loaded Configuration File : /usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini
Scan this dir for additional .ini files :  /usr/local/php5/php.d

Comment: That is a `phpinfo()` run form a script using the browser right? You are not running a phpinfo from your PHP CLI are you??

Comment: Its more likely to be something like `/etc/php5/apache2/php.ini` or maybe `/usr/local/apache2/php.ini`

Comment: @RiggsFolly: yes, phpinfo() from CLI also showed the same php.ini file: 
/usr/local/php5/lib/php.ini

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you remove the preceding semi-colons?

```
display_errors = Off
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

display_startup_errors = Off
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

error_reporting = 0
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

Comment: That part of the `php.ini` file is **Documentation only**, Look for another reference to each parameter you want to change after that section in the ini file.

Comment: It's exactly what OP provided. I rarely make assumptions. I go with what is provided to me. But thanks for the downvote even though I resolved the issue for him.

Comment: Yup, so the OP does not know his way around the `php.ini` file either. Look for the other reference I mentioned and see if I am right or not

Comment: I only mention this in case others see this answer and make the same mistake. As the parameter lower in the file, of course as it comes later in the file, will take preference over any change made in this section.

Answer (score 0):

The semi colons are remarks in php.ini

```
; display_errors
;   Default Value: Off
```

Everything after ; is ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the section you show in your question comes just below a heading like this

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Quick Reference ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; The following are all the settings which are different in either the production
; or development versions of the INIs with respect to PHP's default behavior.
; Please see the actual settings later in the document for more details as to why
; we recommend these changes in PHP's behavior.

; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_STRICT & ~E_DEPRECATED
;   Development Value: E_ALL
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT
```

This section is just for documentaion, and is not where the real parameters are located. If you look lower in the file you will see the real parameter locations

```
; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; For production environments, we recommend logging errors rather than
; sending them to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On
```

This is where you should make the changes to the actual parameters because if you change the section you mention, the parameter changes will be overridden by the **real** paramters specified below.

> Also dont forget to restart Apache after saving any changes to the `php.ini` or the changes will not take effect.